# How do I make Emacs dired mode display unicode characters in windows?

Tags: windows, emacs, unicode, multibyte, dired

I have emacs 23.3 running on windows XP and I work on some files whose filenames contain a combination of English & devanagari or tamil characters (e.g., `que.प्रश्न.txt` or `ans.பதில்.txt`).

When I visit the directory containing this file in Dired, these file names don't appear correctly, even though I can see the names in windows explorer. Dired displays names like "deva~1.txt" for filenames that have begin with english characters but in case of names fully composed of non-english characters it displays something like "47d1~1.txt".

I suppose this has something to do with what Windows internally returns to emacs but I notice that running `dir` on command-prompt at the same directory displays the full names (even though `cmd` just renders all non-english characters as `?` symbol).

Is there anyway I can enable dired to render filenames with non-english characters correctly?

Comment: I find that dired shows me empty spaces in place of the unicode characters, and this is the case in both NTEmacs and on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually a limitation of Emacs's implementation.  Emacs uses Windows primitives that date back to before Unicode, so any filename with chars that cannot be encoded in your "codepage" will be replaced with the mangled foo~1 name (if your file system is VFAT) or something else in other cases.  Hopefully we will soon switch over to the "new" Windows primitives that use UTF-16 (IIRC) and do not suffer from such problems any more.  But you may have to wait for Emacs-25.1 for that.  It may happen sooner if you give us a hand, tho ;-)

Comment: Stefan, thanks for the clear answer. I am really interested in seeing this and some other unicode-related improvements to emacs. I am willing to help in any way I can.

Comment: @koushik: then, if you have some experience writing C code in Windows, join us on the `emacs-devel` mailing-list.

Comment: Stefan... at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Name-Coding.html it says emacs does use Unicode primitives, but not in 24.3, or at least I have files I can't open because of their naming. What's the current, real story? Still on track for v25?

Comment: Actually, our hero Eli implemented it for 24.4.

Comment: @Stefan: doesn't seem to be working: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15303/open-russian-file-names-on-windows